# Limiting script variables to specific sheets in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a functioning script working within Google Sheets. The document has multiple sheets. As such, I wish to be able to have one script that is capable of automating a time stamp on all of the sheets.

I have managed to get the script running on all sheets... however I wish to be able to have two separate variable columns and have them act independently of each other. For instance, **var cols** would affect **SHEET 1** and **var colx** would affect **SHEET 2**. Would this be possible?

```
function onEdit(e) {
var s = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
var cols = [8];
var colx = [4, 9, 14];
var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "M/d HH:mm:ss ") 
var r = e.source.getActiveRange();

if (s !== "SHEET 1" && s !== 'SHEET 2' && s !== 'SHEET 3'|| cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) ==-1 && colx.indexOf(e.range.columnStart)    ==-1|| 
!e.range.getValue()) return;
 e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(curDate); 

 };
```

Novice scripter here, thanks for your patience.
I was thinking that it would involve specifying the Sheet names with var cols and var colx but am unsure if this is the right approach.

Thanks in advance for any help!!!!!

Comment: This isn't a Google Apps Script specific problem, you should mark up Javascript aswell in tags.

Comment: Thanks Kriggs! added the tag to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend changing your `if` statement to be a little more clear in what you're trying to accomplish.  It seems like you are either trying to

1. Apply a timestamp when any column **except** `cols` or `colx` is matched, or
2. Apply a timestamp **only** when the columns defined in `cols` or `colx` are matched.

### Scenario 1: Apply timestamp except when column is matched

```
if (s == "SHEET 1" && cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) == -1) {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(curDate); 
} else if (s == "SHEET 2" && colx.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) == -1) {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(curDate); 
} else {
    return;
}
```

### Scenario 2: Apply timestamp only when column is matched

```
if (s == "SHEET 1" && cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) != -1) {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(curDate); 
} else if (s == "SHEET 2" && colx.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) != -1) {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(curDate); 
} else {
    return;
}
```

### Scenario 3: Skip the timestamp if the cell is empty

```
if (s == "SHEET 1" && cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) != -1 && !e.range.getValue()) {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(curDate); 
} else if (s == "SHEET 2" && colx.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) != -1 && !e.range.getValue()) {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(curDate); 
} else {
    return;
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Scenario 2 is what I was looking for! Have yet to dabble with else if statements yet but see how much more logical your presentation of the if statement is than my initial attempt. Thank you so much for the help! I had kinda just banged the two statements together and hoped that they would magically work... the problem being that they would work everywhere instead of within limits. Thanks again!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Hi again Eric, with regard to the help you gave me i was wondering if you would mind further explaining something in your example. Specifically this part:

     else {
       return;

Is that derived from my initial:
    !e.range.getValue()) return;

I was wondering if it would be possible to keep the  !e.range.getValue()) return;     contained within the if statements.

eg. 
    **if (s == "SHEET 1" && cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) != -1) {
   !e.range.getValue()) return;
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(curDate);** 

however this seems to cause a syntax error. what would cause this?

Comment: looks like I may have sussed it out... if ((s === 'SHEET 1' || s === 'SHEET 2') && cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) === -1) {
  if (!e.range.getValue()) return;
  e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(curDate);
}

Comment: I would recommend integrating it into the existing `if` statements.  Are you trying return if the cell is empty? I've added a "scenario 3" that might help out.  However, if your method works, I'd say that's just fine.